# Changing value of background-image using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, string, replace, background-image

I'm trying to change the background image of a span using jQuery. Basically I want to keep switching between 'arrow-down.png' and 'arrow-up.png'
The logic is:

1. I click on the #profile-li span
2. script checks what background image the .arrow-img span has currently got
3. if it contains 'down' change it to 'up'
4. else change 'up' to 'down'

Up to point 2. it works fine - it goes to the 'if' statement, but when I get the alert box the image is still 'arrow-down.png'. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here:

```
 $("#profile-li").click(function () {
        var bgValue = $("#profile-li").children(".li-title").children(".arrow-img").css('background-image').toString();
        if (/down/i.test(bgValue)) {
            (bgValue).replace('down', 'up');
            alert(bgValue);
        }

        else
            $("#profile-li").children(".li-title").children(".arrow-img").css('background-image').replace('up', 'down');
    });
```

Could someone please help me to find and fix my mistake?

Comment: We can provide a more specific answer if you create a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) of what you have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`toString()` returns a string and not a jquery object so changing `bgValue` (the string...) has no effect on your page.

I would simply add a class with the down-arrow, set the up-arrow as the default background and use jquery's [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) method.

Something like (I´d need to see the html for an exact solution):

```
$("#profile-li").click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass("down_arrow");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I might use this solution in the end, if nothing else works. 
But I would really, really like to find out why my code doesn't work. It looks fine to me and I'm dying to know the answer. So if you have any ideas, please let me know :)

Comment: @Nagareboshi Take a look at the first line of my answer, in your `if` statement you are manipulating a string, not a jquery object that represents part of the DOM.

Comment: I know this. This if just for the testing purpose. If the up/down replacement was successful, I would assign the new value to the object. But for some reason the 'down' remains 'down' :/

Comment: @Nagareboshi `replace()` does not change the string it is used on, it returns the result which you are not assigning to anything, you should be able to use it like: `var nValue = bgValue.replace('down', 'up');`

Comment: @Nagareboshi You're welcome! Please don´t forget to mark the answer as accepted if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You might try this (untested)

```
$("#profile-li").click(function (){
    if($(this).children(".li-title")
              .children(".arrow-img")
              .css('background-image') == 'url(default/images/image-down.png)'){
        $(this).children(".li-title")
               .children(".arrow-img")
               .css('background-image', 'url(default/images/image-up.png)')
    }
    else{
        $(this).children(".li-title")
               .children(".arrow-img")
               .css('background-image', 'url(/default/images/image-down.png)')
    }
});
```

`image-down.jpg` and `image-up.jpg` are whatever the names of the bg images are named.

**EDIT**

To be clear, as per the comments below, you also need to include the right file path and CSS background-image syntax. Changed above.

Comment: the problem is that the "$("#profile-li").children(".li-title").children(".arrow-img").css('background-image').toString();" returns something like: "url(http://domain.com/default/images/image-down.png)".
So obviously this value doesn't match "image-down.png".

Comment: Of course, @Nagareboshi.  I figured you would deal with the file path, as you knew what it was. I will clarify in my answer.

Comment: you don't understand. "$("#profile-li").children(".li-title").children(".arrow-img").css('background-image').toString();" returns FULL path of the file. And this can change eg. if I decide to change the domain. And the string url("domain.com/default/images/arrow-down.png") is not equal to this one url("default/images/arrow-down.png").

Comment: Thanks @Nagareboshi.  I understand what you mean.  Mine is only a code example.  You need to rework some of the content to suit your situation.  Of course, the domain can change... then you need to switch the code. ;-)  fyi... the reason I cut off some of the URL was so it would fit on the screen.

Comment: but it's not a good and professional practise to use full url in your code I'm afraid. I haven't seen anyone doing this. The code needs to be flexible and not depend on your project's location.
But anyway, thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

make use of "$(this)" inside your function.
it would also help if you posted your html

Comment: the html is simple: <li id="profile-li"><span class="li-title">Profile<span class="arrow-img">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></span></li>

Answer (score 0):

You could always change it up so you have two classes in the CSS. This lets you have the ability to change the look of the arrows in the future and not have to change anything in the script file.

```
.up {
    background-image: arrow-up.jpg;
}
.down {
    background-image: arrow-down.jpg;
}
```

Then in the JS you can just add or remove the class as you need it.

```
$("#profile-li").click(function (){
    var arrow = $(this).children(".li-title").children(".arrow-img");
    if (arrow.hasClass("up")) {
           arrow.addClass("down").removeClass("up");
    } else {
           arrow.addClass("up").removeClass("down");
    }
});
```